# Is it possible to make a list partition in PostgreSQL based on a join of the partition list key?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

Consider the following tables

```
Table "public.Foo"
      Column      |            Type             |         
------------------+-----------------------------+
 foo_id           | integer                     | PK
 bar_id         | integer                     | FK to bars
....


Table "public.Bar"
      Column      |            Type             |         
------------------+-----------------------------+
 bar_id           | integer                     | PK
....

Table "public.very_big"
      Column      |            Type             |         
------------------+-----------------------------+
 foo_id           | integer                     
....
```

Bar is mapped to Foo such that a Bar has many Foos. There are < 50 Bars, each of which has hundreds of Foos. Then, I have a separate table that is quite large, > 200 million rows, which references Foos (among other tables), creating a large composite primary key that results in a large table size.

In an ideal world, I'd like to partition very_big on bar_id, without having to add a column for bar_id, by just using the reference of foo_id. This would give a good number of partitions, 1-50 order of magnitude, while partitioning on foo_id directly would be thousands, which is advised against in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

In a sense, this ideal world is a list partition based on a join. Based on the documentation, it doesn't seem like this is possible to me. It also raises some hairy questions, like what happens to data in one partition if the foo-bar relationship is changed such that the data would have to move partitions? Because of this, this doesn't seem possible/doesn't make sense.

One alternative is to use a manually defined list partition. This will result in each manually defined range having on the order of 300-500 values. Some cons of this approach are 1) if references change between foo and bar as discussed above the partition is totally ruined (I don't foresee this happening, otherwise I wouldn't be considering this solution, but it's still a downside) 2) It's possible large, non-contiguous list partition definitions of 300-500 values would have poor performance for the postgres query planner. 3) Newly added Foos won't have a place to go based on pre-defined lists, as they won't have been added to the partition definition.

Another alternative is to suck it up and add a column for bar_id to very_big, but this is non-normal and redundant.

Is the "join" based list partition possible? (I think not)

If not, are there performance consequences of non-contiguous, 100+ order of magnitude list based partitions? (Unsure, but there are other costs here)

Are there other solutions to this problem I am potentially missing? I'm planning to go with the "denormalized" solution for the moment and add bar_id to very_big and define the partition based on that

Thank you

Comment: I (unfortunately) think you are right in your analysis of the problem. If you go for the denormalization solution, it would be a good idea to change the foreign key to Foo to include both foo_id and bar_id so that no data inconsistencies appear.

Comment: @edruid, great callout; I like the idea behind that extra constraint, thank you